# Cannot Replace Pandas Column With Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas column with string value entries, which I have ensured are strings via

`df[col].astype(str)`

And I have created a dictionary out of an enumeration of these string values that takes the form

`{...'hello': 56, 'yello': 71,...}`

I have tried multiple map/replace implementations, but I cannot get the string values to update with their dictionary integer.

`df[col].replace(lambda s: inv_map.get(s) if s in inv_map else s)`

Is the most recent one I have tried.  I dont get any errors or warnings, it simply doesnt map the values.

Comment: I think you are looking for `apply` not replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `apply` i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":['hello','yello','bye','seeya']})
inv_map = {'hello': 56, 'yello': 71}
col = 'a'
df[col]=df[col].apply(lambda s: inv_map.get(s) if s in inv_map else s)
```

```
0       56
1       71
2      bye
3    seeya
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace values in a column by the values in a dictionary using `map()`:

```
# sample data
df
     a
0  asd
1   er
2  sdf
3  qwe

dic = {'asd': 21, 'er':90}

df['dic_value'] = df.a.map(dic)
df
     a  dic_value
0  asd       21.0
1   er       90.0
2  sdf        NaN
3  qwe        NaN
```

Comment: I think my issue was that I was targeting my column via df[col] as opposed to df.col...

Comment: It will work either way. I could have also used `df['a'].map(dic)`. You'll need to use quotes.

Comment: @redress Please accept an answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['hello', 'yellow'], columns=['col_name'])
inv_map = {'hello': 56, 'yellow': 71}

df.replace(dict(col_name=inv_map))

    col_name
0   56
1   71

# or just use 

df['col_name'].replace(inv_map)

0    56
1    71
Name: col_name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).